# Why error for login and password gets deleted right after being created React-Hook-Form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I`m trying to make a login form in react using react-hook-form, but when I try to submit with null input values - errors for "password" is getting deleted after rerender. And "login" errors are not being displayed at all.

If I do the same thing with every other registered name (for example "captcha" or "login1/password1"), everything works just fine.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/8n5rmr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Here`s my code:

```
import React from "react";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";

const Login = (props) => {
    const {
        register, handleSubmit, clearErrors, setError, reset, formState: {
            errors
        },
    } = useForm({
        mode: "onBlur", defaultValues: {
            login: "", password: "", rememberMe: false, captcha: "",
        }
    })

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        reset({
            login: "", password: "", rememberMe: false, captcha: "",
        }, {keepErrors: true});

    }
    console.log(errors);
    console.log(props);
    debugger
    return (<form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    >
        <input
            {...register("login", {
                required: "Login is required", minLength: {
                    value: 4, message: `Min length is ${4}`
                }
            })}
            placeholder={"Login"}
            onFocus={() => clearErrors(["login", "server"])}
        />
        <p>{errors.login?.message}</p>
        <input
            {...register("password", {
                required: "Password is required"
            })}
            placeholder={"Password"}
            onFocus={() => clearErrors(["password", "server"])}
        />
        <p>{errors.password?.message}</p>
        <input
            {...register("rememberMe",)}
            type={"checkbox"}
        />
        <br/>
        <input
            {...register("captcha", {
                required: "Captcha is required"
            })}
            placeholder={"Captcha"}
            onFocus={() => clearErrors(["captcha", "server"])}
        />
        <p>{errors.captcha?.message}</p>
        <input type={"submit"}/>
    </form>)
}
```

[First rerender after submitting with empty inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6uMe.png)

[Second rerender after submitting with empty inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgUs7.png)

[What should it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTcL9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused because you are clearing the errors when the inputs get focused.

Focusing fields with error is default behavior of the `react-hook-form` library, you can read about it [HERE](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#shouldFocusError).

You can add `shouldFocusError: false` to your code to prevent the fields from getting focus when they have an error.

Here is an example:

```
const {
        register, handleSubmit, clearErrors, setError, reset, formState: {
            errors
        },
    } = useForm({
        shouldFocusError: false // ADD THIS HERE
        mode: "onBlur", defaultValues: {
            login: "", password: "", rememberMe: false, captcha: "",
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering around i found out that the form always jumps the focus from first input to second input no matter the order of the inputs, that's why the errors keep disappearing due to the `onFocus`; one way of work around is using `onClick` instead. I suspect the focus problem is from the library `react-hook-form` since the first input should receive focus when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Too bad I cant mark it as useful since i dont have enough reputation.